# Error loading class 'solr.VelocityResponseWriter'

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr6

I am trying to setup `/browse` functionality of solr, referring this [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/velocity-search-ui.html). I have done the following

1. Added `velocity-1.7.jar`, `velocity-tools-2.0.jar`, `commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar`, `commons-collections-3.2.2.jar` to lib directory in my solrhome
2. added

   `<queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter">
   <str name="template.base.dir">${velocity.template.base.dir:}</str>
   <!--
   <str name="init.properties.file">velocity-init.properties</str>
   <bool name="params.resource.loader.enabled">true</bool>
   <bool name="solr.resource.loader.enabled">false</bool>
   <lst name="tools">
   <str name="mytool">com.example.MyCustomTool</str>
   </lst>
   -->
   </queryResponseWriter>`
   to `solrconfig.xml`

Comment: Are the jars actually being loaded? Check the output at the start in the log file to see which files are being loaded. What is the exact error message?

Comment: I see this message so I assumet the jars are being loaded successfully. 
`2018-05-17 20:07:54.148 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader [null] Added 8 libs to classloader, from paths: [/Users/solr-6.5.1/solrhome/lib]
`
I get this error `Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.VelocityResponseWriter'`

Also when I untar the jars and look for VelocityResponseWriter.class I am unable to find it. 
@MatsLindh

Comment: Ah, the Solr response writer isn't part of the `contrib/` directory - that's just the external dependencies. You need `solr-velocity-7.3.1.jar` located under `dist` in the binary zip. Try that one.

Comment: ah.. that fixed the error.. I wonder why have they not mentioned about `dist` in the documentation.. but now when I try to load `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection_name/browse` its not loading anything instead the page just redirects to `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/`

Comment: @MatsLindh Do I need to perform any additional step for it to work?

Comment: That's not the URL for the velocity interface - it's /solr/collection/browse - no anchors - those are just for the admin interface.